# WPF UserControl : Keep multiple linked dependency properties in sync without recursive loop causing Stack Overflow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, user-controls

I am trying to create a simple user control for an immutable object with multiple properties.

The immutable object **and a its properties** should be exposed trough dependency properties of the user control.
When one dependency property changes, others need to change as well.

I think the best way to explain my problem is with a small example:

Let's say I have an immutable class Person.
The Person class has two properties: FirstName and LastName.

Person class:

```
    public class Person
    {
        private readonly string _firstName;
        private readonly string _lastName;
        public string FirstName => _firstName;
        public string LastName => _lastName;

        public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            _firstName = firstName;
            _lastName = lastName;
        }
    }
```

I want to make a view that has 2 text boxes: one for the First name and one for the last. I also want this view to have a dependency property that allows binding to the Person object created by the input of these two text boxes.

When I change the FirstName, this should result in a new Person.
When I change the LastName, this should result in a new Person.
When I change the Person, also FirstName and LastName need to be changed.

Usage example:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <local:PersonView Person="{Binding PersonA, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></local:PersonView>
            <local:PersonView Person="{Binding PersonB, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></local:PersonView>
            <local:PersonView Person="{Binding PersonC, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></local:PersonView>
        </StackPanel>
```

User control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AutoMuse.GlobalSettings.PersonView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AutoMuse.GlobalSettings"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:PersonView, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
             d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="0">
            <Label>First Name</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="0">
            <Label>Last Name</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock>Welcome: </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue=-, FallbackValue=-, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind of user control:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PersonView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PersonView : UserControl
    {
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FirstName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FirstName", typeof(string), typeof(PersonView), new PropertyMetadata(OnFirstNameChanged));

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LastNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LastNameProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LastName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LastNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LastName", typeof(string), typeof(PersonView), new PropertyMetadata(OnLastNameChanged));

        public Person Person
        {
            get { return (Person)GetValue(PersonProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PersonProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FullName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Person", typeof(string), typeof(PersonView), new PropertyMetadata(OnPersonChanged));


        private static void OnLastNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is PersonView personView)
                personView.OnLastNameChanged((string)e.OldValue, (string)e.NewValue);
        }
        private static void OnFirstNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is PersonView personView)
                personView.OnFirstNameChanged((string)e.OldValue, (string)e.NewValue);
        }
        private static void OnPersonChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is PersonView personView)
                personView.OnPersonChanged((Person)e.OldValue, (Person)e.NewValue);
        }

        private void OnFirstNameChanged(string oldValue, string newValue) 
        { 
            Person = new Person(newValue, Person?.LastName); 
        }
        private void OnLastNameChanged(string oldValue, string newValue) 
        { 
            Person = new Person(Person?.FirstName, newValue); 
        }

        private void OnPersonChanged(Person oldValue, Person newValue)
        {
            FirstName = newValue?.FirstName;
            LastName = newValue?.LastName;
        }

        public PersonView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

The main focus is on these methods:

```
        private void OnFirstNameChanged(string oldValue, string newValue) 
        { 
            Person = new Person(newValue, Person?.LastName); 
        }
        private void OnLastNameChanged(string oldValue, string newValue) 
        { 
            Person = new Person(Person?.FirstName, newValue); 
        }

        private void OnPersonChanged(Person oldValue, Person newValue)
        {
            FirstName = newValue?.FirstName;
            LastName = newValue?.LastName;
        }
```

Unfortunately, when setting the Person, this will set the FirstName, this will set the Person, this will set the FirstName, and so on ...
You can see that this leads to a loop and thus a stack overflow.

I can think of a few work arounds:

- adding a boolean field to prevent the recursive calling (e.g: _handlingOnPersonChanged) and then checking this.
- using the Equals function to only set a new value on inequality.

However I don't think these are the right solution to this problem.

What would be a good way to keep multiple Dependency Properties in sync without having this kind of recursive loop?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

It seems **the example did work correctly**. Probably because under the hood the values are compared and the value changed callback is only called when the value actually changes. In my real application, the dependency properties like FirstName and LastName are not strings, but non-primitive custom types. These have both an Equals method and Equality operator overloads, but it seems that nor the Equals method, nor the '=='/'!=' are called. This makes that the value changed callback is called everytime, regardless of equality of old and new value. And this again results in the recursive loop: PersonChanged > FirstNameChanged > PersonChanged > FirstNameChanged > ...

As ASh has pointed out: calling OnPropertyChanged(...) myself was not needed, since this is handled under the hood, so these are removed. Removing them did not solve the problem however.

Answer (score 1):

don't call OnPropertyChanged for any property. if there is any value change, it will be handled by property change callback.

```
private void OnPersonChanged(Person oldValue, Person newValue)
{
    if (FirstName != newValue?.FirstName)
        FirstName = newValue?.FirstName;
    if (LastName != newValue?.LastName)
        LastName = newValue?.LastName;
}
```

Comment: Hi ASh, thank you for your answer, I edited my question with your reference. Unfortunately, with regards to the problem, it does not make any difference.

Comment: @CédricMoers, does it improve situation, if you check equality before assignment? (I thought DP does it internally)

Comment: It does compare old and new internally for strings and probably other types as well. So in the example it is handled by the dependency prop. The method 'sees' that the new value equals the old and concludes that there is no reason for change, so the recursive loop is avoided. But when using a non-primitive type, for some reason it does not use the Equals method, nor any of the Equality overloads. So then it basically goes into an recursive loop, because there is nothing stopping it. Please also see my own answer, where I also manually check for equality.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution as mentioned in the original question (using the Equals function to only set a new value on inequality). **I do wonder however if there is a simple solution that does not require an Equality method?.** Implementing equality methods is not that hard, but still wondering out of curiousity.

---

I made a wrapper for the string to see what would happen if the property type for FirstName/LastName is not a primitive type to simulate my real-world application. In this case it is a simple StringWrapper:

```
    public class StringWrapper : IEquatable<StringWrapper>
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() => Value;
        public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as StringWrapper);
        public bool Equals(StringWrapper other) => other != null && Value == other.Value;
        public override int GetHashCode() => -1937169414 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Value);

        public StringWrapper(string str)
        {
            Value = str;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(StringWrapper left, StringWrapper right)
        {
            return EqualityComparer<StringWrapper>.Default.Equals(left, right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(StringWrapper left, StringWrapper right)
        {
            return !(left == right);
        }
    }
```

For what I could see, the Equals method, not the == or != operator is **not** called automatically (I could be wrong in this). But adding it manually and checking for equality before setting resolves the issue, as shown below.

```
        private void OnFirstNameChanged(StringWrapper oldValue, StringWrapper newValue) 
        { 
            if (newValue != oldValue)
                Person = new Person(newValue?.Value, Person?.LastName?.Value); 
        }
        private void OnLastNameChanged(StringWrapper oldValue, StringWrapper newValue) 
        {
            if (newValue != oldValue)
                Person = new Person(Person?.FirstName?.Value, newValue?.Value); 
        }

        private void OnPersonChanged(Person oldValue, Person newValue)
        {
            if (newValue != oldValue)
            {
                FirstName = newValue?.FirstName;
                LastName = newValue?.LastName;
            }
        }
```